# Bash - Variable with variables and commands

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I've been trying to create a variable that holds the value of other values and also commands to be issued. I've found individual answers to both those sitatuons, but I'm struggling to put them together.

$DID and $SECTOR below are two variables that are already established.

```
DATAPARMS=$($DID,$SECTOR,date,uptime | sed 's/^.* up \+\(.\+\), \+[0-9] user.*$/\1/',ls -I README.txt /var/www/html | wc -l,grep "VERSION" /root/config | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g')
```

The individual commands (grep, sed, etc) can be ignore.

I would then like to call this with echo:

```
echo "$DATAPARMS"
```

Any pointers on how best to accomplish this? Thank you very much!

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!")

Comment: Bash variables don't allow nested structures -- you can't have arrays inside arrays. Trying to do complex structured data with bash is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), variables should not be used to store code. Use a function instead, as follows:

```
getDataParams() {
  echo "$DID,$SECTOR,date,uptime" | sed 's/^.* up \+\(.\+\), \+[0-9] user.*$/\1/'
  ls -I README.txt /var/www/html  | wc -l
  grep "VERSION" /root/config     | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g'
}

getDataParams
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can apply sed to "uptime", and keep all within 1 line?

Comment: `foo() { uptime | sed '...'; }` -- the only noteworthy thing about putting a function definition all on one line is that you need to end whatever command precedes the closing `}` (as with a `;` or `&`), or else it's parsed as an argument.

Comment: That said, as a rule, I advise against using one-liners -- clarity is generally more valuable than terseness.